# 'undefined' is returned after comparing numbers with a var set to POSITIVE_INFINITY and MAX_VALUE in javascript

Tags: javascript

Description:
I am working on some exercises to get familiar with Javascript.  One of the question asks me to find the smallest number in a given object below.

```
var myObj = { key: [5, 8, 1, 4] };
```

I set my initial value of `smallest` to `POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `MAX_VALUE`. 
 After I ran my program (see below), `undefined` was returned.  However, when I set `smallest` to `99999`, the program is executed correctly.

My Question: What causes undefined returned when I set my variable, smallest, to POSITIVE_INFINITY and MAX_VALUE ?  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
var myObj = { key: [5, 8, 1, 4] };

function getSmallest(obj, key) {

  //var smallest = Math.POSITIVE_INFINITY;  //---> undefined is returned
  //var smallest = Math.MAX_VALUE;  //--->undefined is returned
  var smallest = 99999;  //---> Correct result is returned

  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || !Array.isArray(obj[key]) || obj[key].length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  for (var i in obj[key]) {
    if (obj[key][i] < smallest) {
      smallest = obj[key][i];
    }
  }

  return smallest;
}

var output = getSmallest(myObj, 'key');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: There is no `MAX_INFINITY`

Comment: Aside: there is a slightly shorter method to find the lowest number in that array: [`Math.min.apply(null, obj.key);`](https://jsfiddle.net/bj8tcsax/). (ES5 version. ES6 version using the spread operator is Bergi's example immediately below this comment).

Comment: Any reason why you would not just use `Math.min(...obj[key])`?

Comment: It's `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;` but just use `Infinity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) and [`POSITIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY) constants are properties of the `Number` object, not of `Math`. You can also use the global [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) constant.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because it's `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, not `Math.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. (Same for `MAX_VALUE`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use Number):

```js
var max = Number.MAX_VALUE;
console.log(max);

var min = Number.MIN_VALUE;
console.log(min);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `MAX_INFINITY` constant in JavaScript. Even `POSITIVE_INFINITY` would not fulfill the task correctly, because that is greater than `MAX_VALUE`. However, you could simply use `Math.min.apply` as mentioned in the comments.

If you really want to understand the logic behind JavaScript number constants, you could use `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, and see that it is less than all JavaScript numbers (including [`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)):

```
Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY < Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER   // true
```

Comment: "*There is no MAX_INFINITY*". Are you sure? *Max Infinity* sounds like a great super hero name to me, right up there with [*Max Power*](https://youtu.be/0GvVbIhKh-M) and [*"To infinity and beyond…"*](https://youtu.be/ejwrxGs_Y_I). ;-)